# datagridview on yesterday

Tags: c#, .net, windows, datagridview

I have a program with dataGridView and I want it to show data which I entered today only and have another button on yesterday and so on(date wise paging).

But everyday when the date changes I want to have a empty datagridview(with 0 rows) if nothing has been update or insert on that day.

Here is my CODE :

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Jobs", con);
            ds.Reset();
            da.Fill(ds);
           // DateTime.Now.AddDays(0);
            //DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(1);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No SQL connection");
        }
        try
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception i)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(i.Message, "Error");
        }
}
}
```

I TRIED WITH DATE TIME ALSO DIDN'T WORK ):

Please guide me..

Comment: So it seems that you just need to add a where clause with a Date in the Sql statement ?

Comment: as jf you have no data for insert or update then ds.tables will have no elements so it might goes in catch block ?

Comment: So can any one of you guys suggest me wat to do
coz im still amateur and just trying new new stuffs

Comment: Just update your SQL Query with where clause and compare `where <dateField> = getdate()` just specify in which datatype you are storing date!! One need to parse in the same format and type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I DID GUYS Here is it for yesterday sql data

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        try
        {
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Jobs Where Jobs_Date = dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) ", con);
            //  da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Jobs", con);
            ds.Reset();
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No SQL connection");
        }
        try
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];                
        }
        catch (Exception i)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(i.Message, "Error");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change your **SelectCommand** to something like

`Select * from Jobs where myDateColumn >= @myDate`

Then assign the value to the parameter

`da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@myDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);`
`da.SelectCommand.Parameters("@myDate").Value = DateTime.Now; //CHANGE DATE FILTER HERE`

*Disclaimer: codes are not tested*

Answer (score 0):

i got it guys

```
 select 

* 
from yourTable
WHERE YourDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
    AND YourDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Or

Today

```
  SELECT GETDATE() 'Today'
  Yesterday

 SELECT DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()) 'Yesterday'
 First Day of Current Week


  SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()),0) 'First Day of Current    Week'
   Last Day of Current Week

   SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()),6) 'Last Day of Current Week'
  First Day of Last Week


  SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),0) 'First Day of Last Week'
  Last Day of Last Week
```